# Angular routing on rails

Tags: ruby-on-rails, angularjs, ruby-on-rails-4, routes, angular-ui-router

How to serve all routes with Angular, being able to perform $http requests to server?
(I'm using html5mode)

If i try to access some address from address line, i get 404 error.

If i write in routes something like:

```
root 'users#index', anchor:false
```

or

```
root 'users#index'
get "*path" => 'users#index'
```

Angular serves all routes from the address line, but I'm not able to perform any requests to server (as they all are redirected to users#index).

Answer (score 0):

Rails' wildcard routes will take priority. So, you'll need to namespace your Angular parts to its own URLs. I usually use `/app` for everything Angular. Here's what I normally put into my `routes.rb` file:

```
get "/app", to: "main#app"
get "/app/*path", to: "main#app"
root to: "main#index"
```

You'll also need to add this tag into the `<head>` of your main layout:

```
<base href="/app/">
```

That will let Angular know to base all URLs off of the `/app` namespace prefix.

Comment: Thanks a lot for your answer. Of course it's working, but it's not really good walkaround, as you are still able to reach some paths from address line, and url is bad.